# Navigation Stack in IOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

If I present a controller with a view controller, is it part of the self.navigationcontroller stack?

In essence:

```
UBSLoginViewController* loginView = [[UBSLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:LOGINVIEW bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];
    navigation.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[loginView presentViewController:[[UBSLoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:LOADINGVIEW bundle:nil] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is the loading view part of the navigation stack? Essentially, I want to present a modal view that will not be part of the root navigation stack.

Comment: Looks like your window's root view controller is a navigation controller. You are presenting your LoadingViewController on your LoginViewController which is the the root view controller of the navigation controller. Does that clear things up?

Comment: @CrimsonChris So does that mean the loadingview is part of the navigation stack or not? So if I were to pop a view controller to go back, would it pop the loading view or not?

Comment: You can tell the LoadingViewController to dismiss itself or you could(should) have the thing presenting it (LoginViewController) do it.

Comment: @chrimsonchris Yes I know all of that, but still, is it part of the navigation stack or is it separate in regards to the navigation controller functions like popViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I present a controller with a view controller, is it part of the
>   self.navigationcontroller stack?

No.

You need to push the view controller onto your UINavigationController in order for it to be on the navigation controller's stack. Right now you are modally presenting on a view controller which is an entirely different concept.

Pushing onto a navigation controller looks something like this.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loadingViewController animated:YES];
```